# Why can't I find Phase to phase voltage like this

Tags: three-phase

I know that that in 3phase ac, 
Vll = sqrt(3) * Vln

I got confused about the sqrt(3) part so I draw phaser diagram and the resultant vector will give me the phase -phase voltage

[image]

But it only gives me 230V , why? 
Can anyone explain how it got sqrt(3) in equation??

Comment: Sure, draw a straigth line from point A to B and then calculate the resultant vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are calculating (the black line) isn't actually \$V_{AB}\$, it is rather the vector sum of \$V_{AN}\$ and \$V_{BN}\$ which is actually just \$-V_{CN}\$.

\$V_{AB}\$ is the voltage of \$V_A\$ referenced to \$V_B\$. To calculate that, you have to subtract one from the other. So the vector sum is actually:

$$V_{AB} = V_{AN} - V_{BN}$$

Doing the calculation, we get:

$$\begin{align}\\
V_{AB} = V_{AN} - V_{BN} &= 230\angle0^\circ - 230\angle120^\circ\\
&=398\angle30^\circ\\
&=(230\sqrt{3})\angle30^\circ\\
\end{align}$$

---

Now lets look at it in a vector diagram:

[image: Vectors for -VCN and VAB]

Notice how the calculation you did (left) and the correct form (right) differ. You can see from the diagram that the line drawn for \$V_{AB}\$ is actually equal to the vector that takes us from the point \$V_B\$ to \$V_N\$ (-\$V_{BN}\$), and then from \$V_N\$ to \$V_A\$ (\$V_{AN}\$).

If you want to calculate that it is exactly \$\sqrt{3}\$, we can do a bit of trigonometry on the newly formed triangle:

[image: Triangle]

From that we can see that:

$$\frac{V_{AB}}{2} = 230\times\sin{60}$$

We know that \$\sin(60) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\$, so we can say directly that:

$$V_{AB} = 2\times230\times\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = 230\sqrt{3} = V_{AN}\sqrt{3}$$

Comment: `VAB=VAN−VBN`, isn't this actually vector difference.??? Thinking back vector sum is the term that confused me

Comment: @Athul, correct, all terms in that are vectors.